# How to send multiple responses in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js

How to send multiple response in node js? In this code I want to send `data` and `data1`

```
function(req, res){
    var classValue = req.query.classID;

    var sql = "SELECT * FROM class WHERE `class_name` ='"+classValue+"'";
      connection.query(sql, function(err, data){
          if(data.length){
              var sql1 = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE `class_id` ='"+data[0].class_id+"'";
              connection.query(sql1, function(err, data1){
                  res.status(200).send(data1);
                  res.status(200).send(data);
              });
          }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You cannot send multiple responses, responses are final. Send all of the data in one response instead.

Comment: res.json({data1,data});

Answer (score 0):

Calling `send` will end the connection, so you can only call it once. You can send back a complex structure as `JSON` easily like this:

```
res.json( { data, data1 } );
```

Note that you have a path where `data.length` might be zero that still needs to be handled. You might consider something like this:

```
function(req, res, next){
    var classValue = req.query.classID;
  var sql = "SELECT * FROM class WHERE `class_name` ='" + classValue + "'";
  connection.query(sql, function(err, data) {
    if (err) return next(err);   // <-- handle errors
    if (data.length) {
      var sql1 = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE `class_id` ='" + data[0].class_id + "'";
      connection.query(sql1, function(err, data1) {
        if (err) return next(err);   // <-- handle errors
        res.json( { data, data1 } );
      });
    }
    else {
      res.json( {data: null, data1: null} ); // or treat it as an error?
    }
  });
}
```

If it's an error condition that the first query gives no results, then you can treat it as an error. Note that I also added error handling using the `next` function (assuming you're using `Express` routing).